# V simple regex use

Tags: vlang

The following code compiles and runs in V 0.4.0 049d685 without a problem but seems to give incorrect results.  I must be doing something wrong, but what is it?

Thanks in advance.

```
import regex

fn main() {
  txt := 'Now is the time for all good men'
  query := r'the'
  mut re := regex.regex_opt(query) or {panic(err)}
  println(re.get_query())           //-> the
  println(re.matches_string(txt)    //-> false
  start,end := re.match_string(txt)
  if start >= 0 {
    println('Match: ${txt[start..end]} between ${start} and ${end}')
  }
  else {println('No match')}        //-> No match
}
```

I was expecting a match to 'the'.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What's the output of `println(re.find_all_str(str))`?

Comment: Note that you are missing a closing parenthesis in line 8: `println(re.matches_string(txt))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matches_string` matches on the whole string. For instance, when using `query := r'.*the.*'` your code will match "the", and output `true`.

As @doneforaiur pointed out, you could use `println(re.find_all_str(txt))` instead of `println(re.matches_string(txt))`, which would output `['the']`.

Comment: Could you update your answer to include the desired output, i.e `re.find_all_str(str)`?

Comment: Thanks to all.  I'm sure that the documentation of the future will make this all clearer.